# Will reusing \sbox-ed cmds reduce DVI/PDF size?

Tags: boxes, gnuplot, rendering, file-size

I wonder wheither reusing `\sbox`'es decreases only `.tex` code or also its final output whether DVI/PDF/... i.e. does TeX expand them while writing DVI or PDF or does the viewer do that? For example `gnuplot` doesn't use `\sbox`'es for identical tickmarks on opposite sides of a plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, saveboxes created with `\sbox` and friends do not reduce the final file size. The content is written to the output file every time it is used in the document.

I actually wrote a LaTeX package `storebox` which provides "storeboxes" which work like saveboxes but only store the content once in the PDF. However, this only works with `pdflatex` in PDF mode, not with DVI, because it uses a feature of the PDF format.

Comment: As I understand DVI file format is a kind of machine language with opcodes, and a stack, so does `\sbox` still reduce file size of DVI? perhaps the conversion to PDF expands them...

Comment: OK, I went through the short DVI file type specification, and there's no display lists or call functions, so TeX necessarily expands repeated `\sbox` usage

Comment: But does the use of saveboxes reduce compilation time, if not file size?  My gut says yes.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: As the content is only typeset once the box is saved it indeed reduces compilation time compared to typeset the content several times by using a macro. The file size is not reduced using `\sbox` as the content is repeated in the output file on every use.

Answer (score 4):

As Martin said, standard LaTeX save-boxes `\sbox`, `\savebox` and `lrbox` environment repeat the DVI, PS and PDF code on every `\usebox`.

Package **`xsavebox`** provides `\xsbox`, `\xsavebox`, `xlrbox` and `\xusebox`, which, apart from box naming, are used in the same way as the standard LaTeX commands, but insert the box content only once as a PDF XObject. Repeated  usage of `\xusebox` inserts references to the object. This works for all common workflows, including **`dvips`+`ps2pdf`**.

E.g. `\xsbox{My Box 1}{Hello world!}` ... `\xusebox{My Box 1}`

or  `\xsbox{MyBoxOne}{Hello world!}` ... `\theMyBoxOne`

Of course, this does not make sense for boxes with little content as in the example because some overhead is introduced. But it may reduce the PDF file size for repeated TikZ graphics, used e.g. as watermarks, and alike.

Comment: Interesting package. Just one remark: when you use `\setlength` it should be, in my opinion, `\dim_set:Nn` which already allows for dimension expressions. Not for `\ratio` from `calc`, but this can be emulated with `xfp`.

Comment: Indeed, the motivation for using `\setlength` in the definition of package/command options was to address potential usage of `calc`-style dimension expressions provided by the user. This ensures the same (expected) behaviour as with the standard `\savebox` command. Otherwise the user code would need to be parsed in order to substitute  `\ratio` or other macros.

Comment: For instance `\setlength{\newYsize}{\Ysize*\ratio{\textwidth}{\Xsize}}` (the example in the manual for `calc`) becomes `\setlength{\newYsize}{\fpeval{\textwidth/\Xsize}\Ysize}`. But both syntaxes are accepted, it seems, so possibly your strategy is good.

Comment: You can avoid overhead of `xfp` at least for such operation, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383689/4686

Comment: Finally, the user decides what goes into te optional width argument of `\xsavebox`/`\savebox` (`calc`-style, `\dimexpr`, ...). And this is beyond the control of the command's implementation. Therefore, `\setlength` was used internally to fully comply with `\savebox` behaviour.