# Divide two lengths

Tags: lengths, dimensions, dimension-expressions, arithmetic, floating-point

How do I divide two lengths and get a length out?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\A
\newlength\B
\newlength\C
\setlength\A{10pt}
\setlength\B{5pt}
\setlength\C{\dimexpr\A/\B\relax}
\begin{document}
\the\C
\end{document}
```

The result is **0.00003pt**, while I want the result to be 10/5=**2pt**.

Comment: How can you get a length from the ratio of two lengths? The ratio between 2 km and 1 km is exactly the same thing as the ratio between 10 pt and 5pt. What would you use this ratio for?

Comment: @egreg: I have increased the size of my `\paperwidth` by a factor given by `\setlength\PPTresizept{\onept*\ratio{\newpaperwidth}{\paperwidth}}`. I then do `\newcommand\PPTresize{\getlength{\PPTresizept}}` to be able to use this factor when I want to resize a rectangle (to maintain the same ratio with the total `\paperwidth`) in tikz using: `\fill (0,0) rectangle (100pt/\PPTresize,50pt/\PPTresize);`. Perhaps there is a better way, but Joseph Wright's solution works.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't divide one dimension by another and get a dimension: the units would cancel. You need the ratio of the two multiplied by the numerator. For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\A
\newlength\B
\newlength\C
\setlength\A{10pt}
\setlength\B{5pt}
\setlength\C{\A*\ratio{\A}{\B}}
\begin{document}
\the\C
\end{document}
```

takes the ratio and multiplies it by `\A`, whereas

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\A
\newlength\B
\newlength\C
\setlength\A{10pt}
\setlength\B{5pt}
\setlength\C{1pt * \ratio{\A}{\B} }
\begin{document}
\the\C
\end{document}
```

gives the 'ratio as a length' (not quite sure that makes sense, but it's what the question asks!).

Comment: Thank you! I used your solution to do `\newlength{\onept}\setlength{\onept}{1pt}` and `\setlength\C{\onept*\ratio{\A}{\B}}`, which gives the correct value of 2pt.

Comment: This calculates A*A/B instead of A/B. Therefore you should use `\setlength\C{1pt*\ratio{\A}{\B}}`, if the unit is pt.

Comment: @dexteritas I've adjusted the answer: I'm not really sure what the questionner was doing ...

Answer (score 8):

You don't need `calc` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\A
\newlength\B
\newlength\C
\setlength\A{10pt}
\setlength\B{5pt}
\setlength\C{\dimexpr \numexpr \A * \A / \B \relax sp\relax}
\begin{document}
\the\C
\end{document}
```

produces `20.0pt`.

I include the `\relax` for clarity, they terminate the expressions and get swallowed. Depending how `\setlength` is coded (not checked) the second one may be superfluous. The first one is superfluous because the letter `s` terminates the `\numexpr` with no error.

Explanations:

- inside `\numexpr` a dimension is converted into an integer representing its value in "scaled points" (1sp = 1/65536pt). This is in fact the TeX internal representation of a length (or rather the `\dimen` part of it, discarding glue components; the LaTeX lengths are actually skips).
- inside `\numexpr` you are allowed to do in temporary doubled precision a so-called "scaling" operation i.e. `(u times v) divided by w`. No overflow will be raised by the first operation, even though the intermediate product exceeds the `2^31-1` TeX bound for numbers.
- finally we convert back to dimen by using explicitely unit `sp`.

Related notes:

- the graphics package internally has some macro to divide dimensions,
- in a another answer of mine which I will will try to find I provided a TeX macro (non-expandable) not using e-TeX doing this division with higher precision than the graphics version.

### Related:

see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/328894/4686, particularly the `\divdef` macro from Part D for non-eTeX macro reliably dividing lengths and producing the result as a fixed point number with 4 or 5 decimal digits (after decimal mark).

This is not using any extra package.