# Drawing one line in different colors

Tags: spacing, color, draw, line

Is there a way to draw a horizontal line with sections of different color and each section of identical length?

The code below will produce the result I'm looking for, but it's not an elegant way to do it.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \textcolor{red}{\rule{5cm}{1mm}}
    \hspace{-.277cm}\textcolor{green}{\rule{5cm}{1mm}}
    \hspace{-.277cm}\textcolor{blue}{\rule{5cm}{1mm}}
\end{figure}
```

Ideally, I want to create the line with relative lengths and be able to colorize it without the need of patching together three single lines.

Comment: Off-topic: If you would put a % sign at the end of lines, you wouldn't need to use the negative `hspace`.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, which produces a `\coloredrule` command which takes a total length for the rule, and a width, and a comma separated list of colors?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}

\newlength{\colorsegmentlength}% Used internally
\newlength{\colortotallength}% Used internally
\newcounter{colorcounter}% Used internally

\newcommand{\coloredrulei}[3]{% {segment length}{rule height}{colors}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \textcolor{##1}{\rule{#1}{#2}}}
  \begingroup\docsvlist{#3}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\coloredrule}[3]{% {total length}{rule height}{colors}
  \setlength{\colortotallength}{#1}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
      \stepcounter{colorcounter}}
    \setcounter{colorcounter}{0}
    \docsvlist{#3}
  \setlength{\colorsegmentlength}{%
    \dimexpr \numexpr \colortotallength / \value{colorcounter} \relax sp \relax}
  \coloredrulei{\colorsegmentlength}{#2}{#3}}
\begin{document}

\coloredrule{20mm}{1cm}{red,orange,yellow,green,blue,violet}

\coloredrule{\textwidth}{2mm}{green,red,yellow,green,red,yellow,green,red,yellow}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(With grateful acknowledgement to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/383689/5404) for division of the lengths.)

Answer (score 2):

This code is simple...but it works! With `line width=3pt` you can increase the thickness of the line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=3pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,yscale=-5,xscale=5]
\draw [color=cyan]  (0,0) -- (5,0) ;
\draw [color=magenta]  (5,0) -- (10,0) ;
\draw [color=brown]  (10,0) -- (15,0) ;
\draw [color=green]   (15,0) -- (20,0) ;
\draw [color=red]   (20,0) -- (25,0) ;
\draw [color=yellow]   (25,0) -- (30,0) ;
\draw [color=red]   (30,0) -- (35,0) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```