# Drawing multiple colored lines in a rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw multiple colored short lines in a rectangle. I've found the following [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429470/drawing-one-line-in-different-colors) which draws colored lines. I'm not sure how to draw several lines, here is my best attempt so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\colorsegmentlength}% Used internally
\newlength{\colortotallength}% Used internally
\newcounter{colorcounter}% Used internally

\newcommand{\coloredrulei}[3]{% {segment length}{rule height}{colors}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \textcolor{##1}{\rule{#1}{#2}}}
  \begingroup\docsvlist{#3}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\coloredrule}[3]{% {total length}{rule height}{colors}
  \setlength{\colortotallength}{#1}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
      \stepcounter{colorcounter}}
    \setcounter{colorcounter}{0}
    \docsvlist{#3}
  \setlength{\colorsegmentlength}{%
    \dimexpr \numexpr \colortotallength / \value{colorcounter} \relax sp \relax}
  \coloredrulei{\colorsegmentlength}{#2}{#3}}


\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=3cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=grey!10]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [box] (population) {};
  \node [anchor=north] at (population.north) {Population};
  \node [anchor=south west] at (population.south west) {$\coloredrule{5mm}{1mm}{green}$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: _Thank_ **you** :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name the first line (e.g. `line1`) you can place your following lines above it (and then sequentially above each in turn).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\colorsegmentlength}% Used internally
\newlength{\colortotallength}% Used internally
\newcounter{colorcounter}% Used internally

\newcommand{\coloredrulei}[3]{% {segment length}{rule height}{colors}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
    \textcolor{##1}{\rule{#1}{#2}}}
  \begingroup\docsvlist{#3}\endgroup}

\newcommand{\coloredrule}[3]{% {total length}{rule height}{colors}
  \setlength{\colortotallength}{#1}
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{%
      \stepcounter{colorcounter}}
    \setcounter{colorcounter}{0}
    \docsvlist{#3}
  \setlength{\colorsegmentlength}{%
    \dimexpr \numexpr \colortotallength / \value{colorcounter} \relax sp \relax}
  \coloredrulei{\colorsegmentlength}{#2}{#3}}


\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{box} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=4cm, minimum height=3cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=gray!10]

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [box] (population) {};
  \node [anchor=north] at (population.north) {Population};
  
  \node (line1) [anchor=south west] at (population.south west) {$\coloredrule{5mm}{1mm}{green}$};    
  \node (line2) [anchor=south west] at (line1.north west) {$\coloredrule{10mm}{1mm}{blue}$};
  \node (line3) [anchor=south west] at (line2.north west) {$\coloredrule{8mm}{1mm}{red}$};
  \node (line4) [anchor=south west] at (line3.north west) {$\coloredrule{20mm}{1mm}{black}$};
  \node (line5) [anchor=south west] at (line4.north west) {$\coloredrule{16mm}{1mm}{yellow}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You get this output:

[image]

(also, note that you have a spelling error in your MWE, it should be "gray" not "grey)